# Display an "expand" button at the bottom of a div only in the case that it's taller than a certain height

Tags: javascript, css, layout

I have a stream of "posts" on the front page of my site that are each represented as individual `<div>`s. The posts can be of any height. When a post is less than `350px` tall, I want to display the full post. When it is MORE than `350px` tall, I want to display the first `350px`, hide the rest with `overflow: hidden`, and give the user an "expand" button to show the whole thing:

[image]

How do I achieve this using as little Javascript as possible (ideally none!)?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divheight = $('#whateverdiv').height();
  if(divheight>350)
  {
     $('#thisbutton').show();
  }
});
</script>

<style>
#thisbutton
{
   display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this without Javascript?